# using predefined structs in c++ in functions

Tags: c++, struct

so i am trying to build a game and i have the following code:

```cpp
// Vector2 is just a struct that represents a vector is 2D space.

// predefining these structs
struct SILO;
struct ICBM;
struct MISSILE;

struct ICBM{
    Vector2 launch;
    Vector2 target;
    Vector2 pos;
    int Velocity;
    
    ICBM(){
        // Implementation not shown
    }
    
    void move(){
        // implementation not shown
    }
    
};


struct MISSILE{
    Vector2 launch;
    Vector2 target;
    Vector2 pos;
    int Velocity;
    
    MISSILE(Vector2 t, SILO origin){
        launch = (Vector2) {origin.Object.x, origin.Object.y};
        target = t;
        pos = launch;
        Velocity = 10;
    }
    
    void move(){
        // implementation not shown
    }
    
};

struct SILO{
    Rectangle Object; // Rectangle has attributes x and y
    Vector2 pos;
    
};
```

I predefined all of the structs in the beginning so they can reference eachother. However, the constructor of the struct MISSILE will result in an error saying that SILO is an incomplete type.

I could change the constructor parameter into MISSILE(Vector2 t, SILO* origin). However, when i try to access the attributes, it will result in the same error.

Is there any way I can solve this problem WITHOUT changing the position of where SILO is defined?

Comment: You need to forward declare SILO.

Comment: that is a possible way, but in the question it says is there a way to do it WITHOUT forward declaring SILO. This solution wont work is 2 structs are referencing eachother

Comment: You need not one, but two things (1) forward declare structs and (2) move member function definitions out of structs and place them after *all* struct decfinitions. The latter point is best implemented by moving struct definitions to one or more header files, and leaving function definitions in .cpp files. No you cannot do that without changing positions.

Comment: it's best you move the class implementations to a .cpp file.

Comment: You might have misread the assignment. Please quote it verbatim, in full and as text directly here. We will help with interpreting your requirements, that is part of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a SILO* in your MISSILE constructor, instead a copy of the whole object?!

```
MISSILE(Vector2 t, SILO* origin){
    launch = (Vector2) {origin->Object.x, origin->Object.y};
```

Comment: Will that work without the forbidden forward declaration?

Comment: yes, but that will still not work because the compiler does not know that SILO has an attribute "Object" until SILO is defined clearly after MISSILE, so it will result in an error

Comment: So it won't work. Would you like to provide a solution which does?

Comment: @a276me: you are absolutely right. The best would be to divide declaration and definition into c/cpp and h files. Or you put the SILO declaration before MISSILE, but you won't do that, why?

Comment: @MiniMik because in more complex projects, i may want to have 2 classes reference each other

Comment: ok, then I think, the easiest way is to divide them in h and c/cpp files.